# HttpGet adding header

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpclient

I am creating a httpClient and I want to add certain header to my HttpGet request
My current code produces the following request.

GET /folder/index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:4444
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)

What I want is to add another header (If-Modified-Since) in that request .
How can I do it?
Thank you :)

```
public String httpGet(String s) {
    String url = s;
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // create new httpClient
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); // create new httpGet object



    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); // execute httpGet
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            // System.out.println(statusLine);
            body.append(statusLine + "\n");
            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            String entity = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            body.append(entity);
        } else {
            body.append(statusLine + "\n");
            // System.out.println(statusLine);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpGet.releaseConnection(); // stop connection
    }
    return body.toString(); // return the String
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the setHeader() method on the HttpGet object like follows.

```
httpGet.setHeader("If-Modified-Since","11/26/2012");
```

I used this [JavaDoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) as a reference.

Comment: can we add ultiple setHeaders on same httpGet object? I want to add more than one header.

Answer (score 1):

Use the setHeader() method on the HttpGet object like follows for the first one

```
httpGet.setHeader("If-Modified-Since","11/26/2012");
```

and then use addHeader() method on the HttpGet object like as follows for the second header.

```
httpGet.addHeader("If-Expires-On","11/26/2014");
```